# Bootstrap's "dropdown open" background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to change the background color of the `li` element when it's `class` changes from `"dropdown"` to `"dropdown open"` on click. I've managed to successfully change the color of the text (which is an `a`). However I can't change the parent `li` properties.

I've copied the code here: http://www.bootply.com/FK88owgjgL. At the end of the CSS file you'll see what I've managed to code concerning background color of the `li` and of it's child. I can't understand why font color works and background doesn't.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is related to the floating elements inside the form, adding clear fix will help.

```
.navbar-right .dropdown-menu form:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

And there is a bit extra background at the bottom due to the parent margin, which can be rest.

```
.navbar-right {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Use this below, if you need to change the background of the search item itself(with the magnifying glass) when active.

```
li.dropdown.open > a:focus {
  color: #000;
  background: red;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/1ub60vcj/3/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want: http://www.bootply.com/rzkcuqK3jA

```
.nav.navbar-right.navbar-nav.bot-search  {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0 -15px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}
```

Comment: This changes it permanently. I want to change the color it shows when you click on it a.k.a when the search form is showed (which in html you can see as a JS adding the "open" class to the `li` element. However, I don't want to change the form background, just the magnifying glass that in the code you've just written, became black..